# Is it possible to restart NodeJS + socket.io with 0 downtime?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am running a game server using PM2 for managing my app, I messed around with their cluster mode:

```
pm2 start app.js -i max
pm2 reload
```

and I suppose the downtime was around 0, but my all my sockets got disconnected nevertheless. I can't use

```
{reconnection: true}
```

for my clients as there are important things that are saved on the dead sockets and also on the server itself, the data lost will crash their browser.

Everytime I need to update my server js files all my clients get connection lost and that's bad.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a server down (or it suddenly restarting) will cause data loss for those items in memory. NodeJS might be fast in restarting, but all those scripts and objects states are lost.

A strategy for you could be two-fold:
1) Store client information in a database, maybe a cache DB like Redis or something that can persist when your server restarts. Each client will have a session token that identifies them and the data you wish to keep with that client.
2) Store that session identifier on connection when the client connects to the server. When the client (automatically) reconnects, they must go through your sequence to a) re-establish their session b) re-join their socket.io room c) restore their state (or get any missed updates).

Comment: So what cluster modes do exactly? aren't their job to preserve somehow that info on the server?

Comment: Cluster mode runs a few copies of the NodeJS application (which is single threaded), though certain things are shared/managed by Node to know which cluster to send work to, etc. Cluster is for a single server running node, mainly to utilize more processing cores (since it's single-threaded)